# C++ friend member function behaviour looks erratic

Tags: c++11, friend-function

I have always tried to avoid friend concept because it beats the purpose of encapsulation. However, I was just experimenting with the concept and the following code fails to compile with the following error:

`main.cpp:29:28: error: ‘int A::a’ is private within this context`

On the other hand, if I just place the class B before class A with forward declaration of class A, it runs fine. Am I missing something really trivial here?

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    int a;

public:
    A() { a = 0; }

    // friend function
    friend void B::showA(A& x);
};

class B
{
    public:
     void showA(A&);
    
    private:
    int b;
    
    
};

void B::showA(A& x)
{
    // Since showA() is a friend, it can access
    // private members of A
    std::cout << "A::a=" << x.a;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    b.showA(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't you first get an `error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class B’` error? Or `error: ‘B’ has not been declared` if you haven't even forward-declared `B`?

Comment: No!. Even earlier I tried to forward declare B and it absolutely made no difference in terms of compiler warnings and error. 
PS: I am using https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler for compilation.

Comment: That's not good, it is truncating the error message, and I can't see where it tells you what compiler it is using. Try with [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/MvxEPEn6s) instead.

Comment: you need a complete class B because you're "using" it.. `friend class B` is allowed in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Mat. goodbolt helped with the correct error: 
`<source>:12:30: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class B'`

Thanks @Swift: understood the issue, however it's not very intuitive. I thought compiler will take care and understand what type of B is.

Would love if someone can detail the explanation as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is, you are using class B within class A, but as you can see B is not declared before it is used.
That is causing an error like this:

```bash
error: 'B' has not been declared
```

and a little further

```bash
error: int 'A::a' is private within this context
```

because the friendship relationship has not been linked due to the first error (as A::a is by default private)

You may try then to forward-declare `B`, like the following

```
#include<..>
class B;
class A {
    int a;

public:
    A() { a = 0; }

    // friend function
    friend void B::showA(A& x);
};
class B{
...
}
...
```

This would generate an error `error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class B'` because a forward declaration only says that a particular
class (here `class B`) will be defined later so you can reference it or have pointers to it, but it does not say what members this class
will have, so the compiler is unable to know if your **future** `class B`would have a `B::showA` method, thus the error, `incomplete type error`. At this time, the compiler does not know if your future class B (used in class A) would have a function `B::showA`.

The simplest solution would be to declare `B` before `A` but then forward declare `A` (with `class A;`) as follows. This way, you tell the compiler - here is my `class B` declaration (it contains a method `B::showA`),
and it uses a class `A` that I will define later. As there is no need to known what would be the content of `A`, it will compile.

```cpp
// as you use class A before it is declared, you need to forward declare it
class A;
class B
{
    public:
     void showA(A&);

    private:
    int b;


};

class A {
    int a;
...
```

This would compile and execute the function `B::showA`.